# deleting user, problems with reauthenticating firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Hello I'm trying to reauthenticate the user before they delete their account but I'm having one problem I can't seem to solve; how do I obtain the user's password if I didn't save it since that would be a privacy issue. I've seen other posts about this but they don't mention how they got the password. This is my code for deleting account:

```
const onDeleteAccountPress = () => {        
    firebase.database().ref('users/'+userId).remove()
    var userReauth = firebase.auth().currentUser

    const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(userReauth.email,userProvidedPassword)
    userReauth.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)
    for(let i =0; i < goalCounter; i++){
        firebase.database().ref('goals/'+(courseGoals[i].id)).remove()
    }

    userReauth.delete()
    .then(function(){
        props.navigation.navigate('Login');
        props.navigation.reset({ index: 0, routes: [ { name: 'Login' } ] });
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
        console.log('there is something wrong')
    })
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user logs in, you can store the password inside `localStorage`, then if the user wants to delete the account, you can get the password from the storage and pass it to the `EmailAuthProvider.credential()` method.

Comment: how do i go about storing the password in localStorage?

Comment: When the user writes the password just add it to storage `localStorage.setItem('user_pass', 'password');`

Comment: react native doesnt allow localStorage so i had to use Async Storage for react native